# Django simple Captcha "No module named fields" error

Tags: django, captcha

Hi I am trying to implement Django simple capcha into my app but when i try to import from view.py "from captcha.fields import CaptchaField" i get an error  "No module named fields". but i am able to import this in the django shell terminal. What else am i missing

Comment: where did you install it. is that in python path?

Answer (score 3):

Did you add `captcha` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py?

If so, did you install it, where did you install it, and is it on your Python path?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem before and I installed django-simple-captcha. It worked finally