# Error during template rendering - No module named fields - Url tags

Tags: python, django

I was building a django website on my PC a few months ago and it worked, I backed the project up, and am now on a new PC and it doesn't work. The error involves the URL tags. I setup the project again on my new PC, however, it doesn't load due to:

> Error during template rendering - No module named fields

It points to: `{% url 'home' %}` in my base template.

Here's the base.html: `<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">`

Views.py:

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    template = "index.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'projectname.views.home', name='home'),
]
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error, this code worked previously.
Thanks

**FULL TRACEBACK (With single quotes):** http://pastebin.com/y8mPiamq

**FULL TRACEBACK (No single quotes):** http://pastebin.com/KetAnYxR

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the post with the full traceback.

Comment: I think it supposed to be `{% url 'home' %}` and I know it says so in the question, but it isnt so in the trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace it seems, that you are using [django-recaptcha](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha) for you contact form. However, when it tries to import it, it fails. Are you sure, that you have it properly [installed](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha#id1)?

Comment: That was me just fiddling, the original code has the single quotes. Same error. EDIT: I updated the original post with a traceback with single quotes.

Comment: See updated answer. Hope it helps. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895296/django-simple-captcha-no-module-named-fields-error) seems to be the same problem, but with different captcha.

Comment: Thank you very much. I uninstalled and reinstalled django-recaptcha, and it works now. Weird... But, thanks for the help!